# Crash in Android UDP server

Tags: android, udp

UPDATED:
I get crash in this Android UDP server example:

```
    //------------------------------------------------------------
public class AsyncReceiveUdp2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int udp=111;
        String txt="";
        byte[] packet = new byte[2000];
        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(packet, packet.length);
        DatagramSocket ds = null;
        try {
            ds = new DatagramSocket(udp);
            ds.setSoTimeout(10000);
            printLog("Ready");
            ds.receive(dp);
            printLog("Received");
            ...
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            printLog("Error1");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            printLog("Error2");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (ds != null) {
                ds.close();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I get my "error2" message.
The reason is "java.net.SocketTimeoutException".
It happens after 10 seconds.
But I sent UDP packet from another computer.
Hmm, I don't understand how it works....
 Any ideas please!

---

Sorry for extra line, the site said that my post is mostly code
Sorry for extra line, the site said that my post is mostly code
Sorry for extra line, the site said that my post is mostly code

Comment: Have you tried on a real device?

Comment: are you running it on a different thread?

Comment: Can we see line number 129 of MyActivity class ?

Comment: line 129 is "ds.receive(dp);". No, I run in main thread. I did not tried on device because have to debug on Emulator. Thanks

Comment: Don't run network tasks on the ui thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run network threads on the UI thread, Android policy forbids it. Make a new thread or use AsyncTask

Comment: I have changed, but I have crash after "ds.receive(dp);".  Hmm, I can't find good full examples on the internet. Thanks

Comment: It crashes on device even if I remove all lines after "ds.receive(dp);" before "catch". And I have discovered that it is very tricky  to get UDP response on Emulator. So I am puzzled....

Comment: Thank you. It certainly should work in a new thread. But it does not work anyway. I've opened new question about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017771/android-udp-server-does-not-receive-packets