# Android UDP server does not receive packets

Tags: android, udp

I have the following code to receive UDP packets:

```
public class AsyncReceiveUdp2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... f_url) {
    int udp=111;
    byte[] packet = new byte[2000];
    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(packet, packet.length);
    DatagramSocket ds = null;
    try {
        ds = new DatagramSocket(udp);
        ds.receive(dp);
        //...
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (ds != null) {
            ds.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

I send UDP data to computer from Android device.
Computer immediately sends response as UDP packet.
I save information to my log file on SD.
And I see, that my app  stays on the line "ds.receive(dp);" and does not run after it.
I've tested on the Android device against a program on computer.
As I understand it is tricky to receive UDP packets on Emulator.
I could not do it.
Redirect does not work for me as it is described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/1oVqP0EuBrg)

Another important issue is to receive all packets, that were sent to the device. Lossless. How to modify the code for that?

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: UDP is not a lossless protocol, use TCP.. it checks whether the packet was received and also it's integrity with an 32bit CRC

Comment: The protocol that I work with is UDP protocol. No chance to choose. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, but you cannot be certain that a packet will be received. That is the difference between UDP and TCP. UDP is faster because you don't check if a packet was received. TCP has that handled including when a packet is malformed (CRC error)

Answer (score 0):

put your receive inside a while(true) loop. When you receive a packet call an if (pkg_received){break;}... or whatever you want to do...
The problem is that you are probably only be receiving one package and you are getting timeout before receiving it.

Code edited and not tested

```
 while(true)
    {


        byte[] message = new byte[60*1024];
        DatagramPacket recv_packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);


        try {
            socket.receive(recv_packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("UDP", "S: Receiving...listening on port " + recv_packet.getPort() );
        String rec_str;
        rec_str=new String(recv_packet.getData)

        Log.d("PACKAGE LENGTH",Integer.toString(recv_packet.getLength()));
}
```